# Duda al momento de mostrar datos que correspondan según Su id. con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Tengo 3 tablas una llamada, Operadores, otra moviles y una ultima llamada vehiculos, la cual me guarda los datos alojados en id's que a su vez se relacionan con las tablas operadores y moviles, debido  a que entre las tablas moviles y operadores, existen dos relaciones una llamada **"hasmany"** y la otra llamada **"belongsto"**, la idea es que no me muestre los id que se me guardan en la tabla vehiculos sino se muestren los valores que pertenecen a cada id que estan en las tablas operadores y moviles.

Por favor me podrian dar una idea de como lograr mostrar los datos desde id, el cual aloja su informacion correspondiente en las tablas operadores y moviles?

*Tabla moviles que contiene varios registros de moviles
*[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
//Controlador "BusesController"

$vehiculosA = Vehiculo::with('vehiculos_abordados')->get();
        return view('buses.index')->with('vehiculosA', $vehiculosA);
```

```
//Vista
@foreach($vehiculosA as $v)
    <tr>
        <td scope="row">{{$v->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$v->operador_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$v->movil_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$v->vehiculos_abordados()->first()->empresa}}</td>
        <td>pRUEBA</td>
    </tr>
      @endforeach
```

```
//Modelo Moviles
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Operador extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'operadores';

        public function moviles()
        {
            //hasMany = Relacion uno a muchos
            return $this->hasMany('App\Movil','operador_id');
            //return  $this->hasMany('App\Vehiculo','movil_id');
        }
}
```

```
//Modelo operadores
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Movil extends Model
{
    public $table = 'moviles';

    public function operador()
    {
            //belongsTO= uno a muchos inversa
            return $this-> belongsTo('App\Operador');

        }
}
```

```
//Modelo vehiculos
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vehiculo extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['movil_id', 'operador_id', 'marca_id', 'carroceria_id','modelo_id','tipologia_id'];

    public function vehiculos_abordados()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Movil','operador_id');
        return $this-> belongsTo('App\Operador');

    }


}
```

Comment: Todo el código relevante a la pregunta va como texto por favor

Comment: Buen dia, ya se agrego el codigo relevante, saludos cordiales!!

Comment: Empiezo a visualizar los problemas que tiene el código, pero para terminar de ampliar respondeme por favor ¿vehiculos es la tabla donde se almacenan únicamente los ids de operadores y móviles?

Comment: Además una edición explicando de mejor manera el resultado que deseas obtener sería muy útil ya que al momento al menos a mi no me termina de quedar del todo clara

Comment: Si en efecto vehiculos es la tabla en donde se guardan mis registros, debido a que tienen relacion con las tablas moviles y operadores, la idea es que esos id´s que se me guaradan en la tbala vehiculos se muestren sus valores corrspondientes mas no el id, saludos cordiales!!

Comment: Entonces la relación que manejas es errónea, no es uno a muchos sino muchos a muchos

Comment: En que parte debo modificar la relacion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para entrar a los datos relacionados no se hace el llamado al ID, si no directamente al nombre de la relación, en este caso si quieres entrar al nombre del operador debes cambiar en tu vista el llamado

de esto:

```
<td>{{$v->operador_id}}</td>
```

a esto:

```
<td>{{$v->operador->name}}</td>
```

Esta es la manera correcta de entrar a los datos relacionados.

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que estaba buscando.!!